# I'm trying to add a video to my webpage in HTML but the video can't be found when browsing for it

Tags: visual-studio, html5-video

I've put the mp4 file in the same folder as the html document but only the video-controller will show up when I run the webpage, not the video itself (I'm using visual studio). Anyone know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>

   <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="mattan.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "**I'm using visual studio**" - Can you please elaborate further?

Comment: Yes sorry! I'm coding in visual studio and run my web-page from there. I'm also using Google Chrome because I read that it supports the mp4 format. The syntax isn't different in visual studio than in other editors? I'm really just starting out on this. Thank you for your response!